# Operations between int/float/string values, too many combinations

Tags: c++, types, operators, combinations

I'm writing a small parser with (currently) 3 scalar data types : int, float and string (char *) :

```
typedef enum eValueType
{
    E_INT, E_FLOAT, E_STRING
}
eValueType;

class CValue
{
protected:

    union
    {
        int _i; float _f; char * _s;
    };

    eValueType _eType;

    // ...
};
```

I would like to overload all the needed operators ( +, -, *, /, &&, ||, etc ) so that i can easily manipulate my CValue objects. The problem is that the number of behaviours to define is combinatorial :

```
CValue operator + ( const CValue & roVal )
{
    switch( roVal._eType ) {
    case E_INT :
        switch( this->_eType )  {
        case E_INT :
            break;
        case E_FLOAT :
            break;
        case E_STRING :
            break;
        }
        break;

    case E_FLOAT :
        switch( this->_eType )  {
        case E_INT :
            break;
        case E_FLOAT :
            break;
        case E_STRING :
            break;
        }
        break;

    case E_STRING :
        switch( this->_eType )  {
        case E_INT :
            break;
        case E_FLOAT :
            break;
        case E_STRING :
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

That's what i get with only 3 types, for a single operator, and without the code that i will have to add in each case. I can't imagine it if i add functions, arrays, etc...

Is there some kind of design pattern or method that I could use to reduce the amount of code i have to write to handle each combination of types for each operator ?

Thank you :)

EDIT : I'd like to avoid C++11 features.

Comment: If one of both is `E_FLOAT`, transform the other into `E_FLOAT`. If one is `E_STRING`, transform it into a proper value (either integral or floating). Then you'll end up with `E_INT x E_INT` and `E_FLOAT x E_FLOAT` operations.

Comment: Btw, are you using `float` rather than `double` because you know what you're doing, or because you don't? ;-)

Comment: I'm using float because i assume it has the same size as int and void *. Thought that may not be true on 64 bits machines, not sure, i havn't thought about this yet.

Comment: @Virus721: on common 64 bit architectures, `int` and `float` are both smaller than `void*`. My point though is that in practice `float` arithmetic hits precision problems quite readily -- of course `double` does too eventually, but it turns out that it's good enough for a *lot* more practical situations than `float` is. Likewise a computer can in practice count to 2^32, but can't count to 2^64.

Comment: Well i can still change that later anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to promote one side (or both, if you like) into a value that can hold all of the important information. Then after promotion you only have one operation for each type.

For example, an expression like `3.33 * 2` should be E_FLOAT * E_FLOAT. `4 / 2` should be E_INT / E_INT. And `3.33 * "3"` should be E_FLOAT * E_FLOAT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll see what i can do with this idea.